# setState does not change state in React in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my code that I'm trying to run. It is supposed to get input from the user (stored in inputData state). And display the output using resultData. However the result displayed is the default empty inputData values (not the values entered by the user).
The inputData variable is successfully receiving the values from the input fields (confirmed by logging). But the resultData object isn't updating with these values when the onSubmit function is called. I have abstracted some of the code here for convenience.

Further Investigation --
Logging inputData inside onSubmit prints out the initial empty values of inputData
Logging inputData inside MyContainer prints out the correct entered values.
Logging resultData anywhere prints out default empty value.

All help is appreciated.

```
export default function MyContainer() {

    const [inputData, setInputData] = React.useState({
        name1: "",
        name2: "",
        ans: ""
    });
    let resultData = {};
    const [resultVisibility, setResultVisibility] = React.useState(false)

    function handleChange(event) {
        // Changes inputData state by calling setInputData

    }

    function onSubmit() {
        // Calculate resultData based on inputData
        resultData = {
             name1: inputData.name1,
             name2: inputData.name2,
             result: 50

        };

        setResultVisibility(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <MyInputComponent
                name1={inputData.name1}
                name2={inputData.name2}
                ans={inputData.ans}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {resultVisibility && <MyResultComponent
                name1={resultData.name1}
                name2={resultData.name2}
                result={resultData.result}
            />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add the `MyInputComponent`, in a [mre]!

Comment: You might want to put resultData into a state as well and set it in `onSubmit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use state for resultData:

```
const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({});
```

Use useCallback and update resultData on submit:

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    // Calculate resultData based on inputData
    setResultData({
         name1: inputData.name1,
         name2: inputData.name2,
         result: 50

    });

    setResultVisibility(true);
}, [inputData]);
```

Comment: Why is state required for resultData?

Comment: Because everything outside the state is being reset on every render.

Answer (score 2):

resultData should be using useState like below

```
const [resultData, setResultData] = React.useState({
        name1: "",
        name2: "",
        ans: ""
    });
```

and onSubmit should be as below

```
function onSubmit() {
        // Calculate resultData based on inputData
        setResultData({
             name1: inputData.name1,
             name2: inputData.name2,
             result: 50

        });

        setResultVisibility(true);
    }
```

Comment: Why is state required for resultData?

Comment: Because variables declared ouside of the state are being reset every render

Comment: using useState hook will make sure the changes in resultData value get reflected on the UI reactively without any external event like refresh.